# When I reload a popup that has this function: onbeforeunload, parent reloades as well, how can I avoid this to happen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function in a "jsp" page:

```
window.open();
```

and in the child I have this function

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {window.opener.loadParametros();}
```

When I update child parent reloads as well, how can I avoid it?

Comment: What?? Please read this  and update the question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist. Nobody can help you with this description of your problem.

Comment: You'll need to show us the `loadParametros` function.

Comment: this is what i have in the function: window.opener.loadParametros('<%=session.getAttribute("idServicio")+"*"+session.getAttribute("nombreServicio") %>','servicios','listByIdServicio');

Comment: And the function does this: $("#contenedor").load(pageToCall), i want to avoid this function to trigger when i update the popup (press f5 or so) it has to be trigger only when i close the popup